# Generate resource file for an ASP.NET Application by Automation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have one ASP.NET Application fully developed and in use. Now i gotto support multiple languages. Application has been inconsistently using resource file already exists. 75% pages uses resource string and 25% uses hard coded string. NOw i want to make support for multiple languages. Can any one please give the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What I do is to manually extract to resources (in CodeBehind, ReSharper 6 helps me a lot). Then I use [this tool](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com) to translate in batch and in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Uwe Keim,.. I don't want to extract resources manually as i have so many pages to do and also i dont enough time to get that time.  So I'm looking for some automation which helps to get all the resource string in a page.

Comment: Probably there _are_ tools for this, also I do think that they force you to use their very own translation framework, whereas I want to keep Microsofts RESX structure. So I would go for the hard way of extracting everything manually. You wouldn't believe how far one can come during one weekend of extracting :-)